# How do I ask the question "Where is it made?" or "Where is it made in"?

Tags: meaning

Sometimes I feel confused about if I should add a preposition, like "come back to Seattle" or "come back Seattle".

If I want to ask a question about where something is made, how to say the question "Where is it made?" or "Where is it made in"?

Comment: You don't normally need [another] preposition in constructions using *where/when*, because these words already imply *at/in/on* some location or day/date.

Comment: You don't necessarily need it, but something like "where did you go to?" is common colloquial English.

Comment: Not your main question but there should be no confusion with Seattle. Being a city Seattle hasn't been anywhere so it can't come back, the expression is telling someone to return _to_ Seattle. "Come back Seattle" would normally only make sense if your dog, child or lover was called Seattle and you wanted them to return to you.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to put this is "Where is it made?"

The rule about adding prepositions at the end of a sentence is: only do it if the sentence doesn't make any sense without it. "Where is it made?" makes sense without a preposition, so don't add one.

This resource cleared up this issue for me: http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/ending-prepositions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use *Where is it made?*

In general, if you can remove the preposition without altering the meaning of the sentence, then it should be left out: *Where is it made in?* has the same meaning as *Where is it made?*

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking without the context of a location, use *Where is it made?* If you are asking specifically about a building or country where something is made, you can use *in*, but you need the context, like this:

> What country is it made in?

Some people will disagree with ending the question with in, and say you should use *In what country is it made?*, but they mean the same thing.

So, context = use in. No context = no in.

Answer (score 0):

**First: Where WAS it made?**
If the thing exists now, it was made in the past, so you need the past tense. On the other hand, if you are writing/talking about something still in production and need a general term, then you will write/ask, "Where ARE THESE made?"

**Second:**
"In" is not a preposition here. It is an adverb describing where the action occurred.

**Where was it made in:**
The version of this I often hear is "where was it made at?" This is redundant because "in" and "at" both refer to "where." Because you already have "where," you don't need "in" or "at."

**Note: "in what country is it made"**
Here, "in" is a preposition. Also, in "It was made in what country," "is" is also a preposition. One easy way to know that "in" is a preposition here is to look for the object of the preposition. Prepositions have objects; adverbs don't.

Answer (score 0):

"Where was it made?" is the right question.

For example:
Person 1 walks into the room with a cool T-shirt.
Person 2 asks: Where was it made?
Person 1: In Germany.

So you see that the replier puts the "in" into the conversation for you. :)